# How do I declare a global variable, set them as workbook in module and use it later?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to declare a global or modulewide variable as workbook and set it in a module for later usage.

For example:

```
public myWorkbook as Workbook 

sub myModule()
    set myWorkbook = Workbooks("myWorkbookName")
    'do some stuff later
end sub
```

And use it in later modules:

```
sub anotherModule()
' do some stuff with myWorkbook
...

end sub
```

But I get byref error during compiling

Answer (score 0):

By default, your code may not be running:

```
sub myModule()
    set myWorkbook = Workbooks("myWorkbookName")
    'do some stuff later
end sub
```

You need to initialize the object pointer in any event handler of Excel. For example, you can use the [Application.WorkbookOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookopen) event which is fired when a workbook is opened.

UPDATE: the problem was the reference.

Comment: Well, ofc it only works if the workbook is actually open. But my problem was the reference. I solved it.